# TypeError: expects parameter 6 to be bool,Magento/framework/Stdlib/Cookie/PhpCookieManager.php:150 setcookie() in magento2.4.2

Tags: cookie, magento2.4.2, allow-cookie, cookie-domain

When go to login on frontend
[image]

In log error
[image]

[image]

Comment: It seems permissions issue?

Comment: @RaulSanchez I run chmod -R 777 var/ pub/ generated/ but it's not working. I update the picture error log